# Applying AlertDialog Styles

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

I am attempting to customize the AlertDialogs in my app.

When it comes to applying the style, my application crashes

I am only applying a background color, like so...

```
<style name="fd_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

And the Java code...

```
public void quit(View v)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.fd_dialog); 
    confirm.setTitle("Quit?");
    confirm.setIcon(R.drawable.questionicon);
    confirm.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Log Out?");
    confirm.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //do some stuff here
        }
    });
    confirm.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    confirm.show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here's the LogCat as requested:

```
08-30 15:25:27.349: W/dalvikvm(2020): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     ... 11 more

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>

08-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):     at com.firsthosted.firstdroid.Home.quit(Home.java:537)

8-30 15:25:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(2020):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: @codeMagic Do you mean an android:onClick from the XML or an onClickListener? It is called from the xml

Comment: at line 537 is the java code i posted

Comment: This exception is thrown when the `android:onClick` attribute of the view (in the layout xml) refers to a method that does not exist on the activity, or it takes the wrong arguments.

Comment: @Alex MDC the method exists, its only when i add the R.style.fd_dialog argument to the AlertDialog that I get the exception

Comment: Then if you have defined the `style` correctly I would try cleaning your project. That is definitely appropriate arguments for that method

Comment: @LouisEvans: if it existed then you wouldn't be getting the crash. If it's failing then your view must be getting inflated with the wrong context (i.e. not the activity that contains the method).

Comment: @LouisEvans what is your min `API` in your `manifest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this ::

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.fd_dialog));

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this helps.  Instead of

AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(**this**, R.style.fd_dialog); use this

AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(**youractivity.this**, R.style.fd_dialog);

Comment: There is a constructor for it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context, int)

Comment: sorry for the mistake.my bad